# How to get representative value from asind?

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, angle, complex-numbers

I am doing angle estimation stuff using two signal's time difference.
I used `asind` function (in MATLAB) in order to get a degree information,
But `asind` sometimes gives complex number.

Which one of real, imag, or abs can give representative angle information?
Pls help me.

Comment: Did my answer help clarify the complex values issue?

Comment: Great! I'd appreciate if you would accept the answer, and maybe upvote too if you feel inclined.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating `asind` for a number with absolute value greater than one, which does not exist.  MATLAB has no choice but to return the [complex result of the formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html).  Even a tiny deviation above `1.0` will cause the result to be complex. For example,:

```
>> asind(1)
ans =
    90
>> asind(1+eps) % eps('double') is about 2.2204e-16
ans =
  90.0000 - 0.0000i
```

This can easily be caused by inaccuracies in floating point computations of the angle.  If you are sure this is the problem and not an error in the computation of the y value, a quick fix is just to take the real component (`real(asind(theta))`). Alternatively, you can check if the input is greater than 1 or less than -1 and rectify the value appropriately.